# How to upgrade Struts version in Lifeary 6.2 CE?

Tags: liferay, struts

How do we upgrade the Struts version to the latest in Liferay 6.2 CE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are thinking of updating the struts version for the Liferay OOTB Portlets, then I have some very bad news for you -- You can't.

For your own portlets I think you can use Struts-2.

Will it be possible to let us know your requirement, so that the community might be able to help with an alternative.

Comment: Hi Advaita, thanks for your prompt response.Because our department is concerned with some vulnerability issues in using Struts so they are requesting to upgrade it to latest version but I can't find any material that suggests how to do so in Liferay.

Comment: I have created a custom login action that overrides the default login in Ext, if its using Struts then I have a problem.

Comment: Is there any other way we can override Login without using struts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're considered about vulnerabilities, you might want to consider using EE - there it's Liferay's problem to fix any issue that you (or others) find, and deliver patches on an SLA. As of the other parts of the questions: You can implement/configure SSO to mitigate login (but it's not the only struts action used in OOTB portlets), but in general you should consider the internal implementation of Liferay to be internal. Unless you can point to a vulnerability. In custom portlets you're free to use any framework (and version) you want - so Liferay's choice of struts doesn't affect you.

Comment: Thanks Olaf! Great inputs! I guess we will just consider upgrading to EE in the future.